# Understanding the Maxwell stress tensor for unidirectional electrostatic fields

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

The Maxwell stress tensor for electrostatic fields only is given by,
$\sigma_{ij} = \epsilon_0(E_iE_j - \frac{1}{2}E^2\delta_{ij})$. Here $\vec E$ denotes the total electric field at a point in the material. Now considering $\vec E = E(x,y,z) \hat{i}$, we get the stress tensor to be $\sigma = diag(\epsilon_0 \frac{E^2}{2},0,0)$.

My question is, given an arbitrary surface $S(x,y,z)$ denoting the bounding surface of the dielectric, how do I picture the stress acting on it at a point $P \in S$. I am primarily trying to understand how it looks at the intersection of $S$ and the X axis suppose. Can someone suggest any articles to understand this, or provide a short explanation.

Comment: It depends on many factors - liquid dielectric, solid dielectric, which medium around the dielectric. The stress tensor in a liquid or solid dielectric has a more complex form than you published here.

Comment: @Alex Trounev , can you kindly provide the links / or inform any articles for the stress tensor in a liquid dielectric ?

Comment: I can recommend L. D. Landau, E. M. Lifshitz (1960). Electrodynamics of Continuous Media. Vol. 8 (1st ed.). Pergamon Press. ISBN 978-0-08-009105-1.